URI path, executable program and its arguments
I was reading for the first time about the concept and syntax of Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) on wikipedia. They give an example :
http://www.example.com/questions/3456/my-document

and they say

"/questions" is the first part of the path (an executable module or
program) and "/3456/my-document" is the second part of the path named
pathinfo, which is passed to the executable module or program named
"/questions" to select the requested document.

But concretely, where is the executable question stored? On the server at location www.example.com?
So for example concerning the URI
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics

it means that somewhere on a wikipedia server which is identified by a certain I.P. (after DNS resolution) by en.wikipedia.org, there is an executable called "wiki" for which we pass "Mathematics" as a parameter?
